# Why is react constant returning blank or null?

Tags: reactjs

Hi i'm following a tutorial in react and i came across this code.

```
formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
}
```

and I have this as my state

```
state = {
    count: 0
};
```

What I don't get is that i point to the state object but I get the value of count. Why is that?

Also, Why am I getting blank when i change formatCount into this.

```
formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state.count;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
}
```

Comment: It's called object destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: where are you calling this function?

Comment: @adel the function works. i got how it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using

```
const { count } = this.state;
```

That means, you are taking the value of this.state.count to a constant named "count"

It can also be written as:

```
const count = this.state.count
```